# Ocaml: Function to uppercase the first element of a list

Tags: ocaml

I have the following function (from the Real World Ocaml book) that works perfectly (with the Core library):

```
 let upcase_first_entry line =
  match String.split ~on:',' line with
  | [] -> assert false
  | first :: rest -> String.concat ~sep: "," (String.uppercase first :: rest);;
```

So when i evaluate:

```
upcase_first_entry ("one,two");;
```

I get:

```
- : string = "ONE,two"
```

From my understanding of the function, the string is first transform into a list of string and then the uppercase function is applied and finally the output is transformed back to a string.
So I tried the following function:

```
List.map ~f:(fun (first :: last) -> (String.uppercase first :: last)) ["one","two"];;
```

where I pass to the function the list directly. But I get the following error:

```
Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a list
       but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
         string * string
```

Can someone guide me as to why this is throwing an error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing the argument `["one", "two"]` directly into the interpreter gives

```
- : (string * string) list = [("one", "two")]
```

That is, a list of pairs of strings *not* a list of strings. You probably meant to type `["one"; "two"]` which is a `string list`. In OCaml, the `,` is used for making pairs and other tuples, even if the parentheses are not given.

The next problem is that `List.map` applies a function to each element of the list and creates a new list. In this situation, it expects an `f` that maps a `string` to something. But your anonymous function maps a list of strings to a list of strings (`string list -> string list`).

In this case, the simplest solution is probably not to use `List.map` and to simply apply your function to the argument.

```
(fun (first :: last) -> (String.uppercase first :: last)) ["one";"two"]
```

The resulting warning indicates that a case is missing. Indeed, the anonymous function is not defined for the empty list. This does not matter for the given argument, but, in general, it would be better to define what should happen, and it gets rid of the warning:

```
(function (first :: last) -> (String.uppercase first :: last) | [] -> []) ["one";"two"]
```